# Are there any precise rules for dueling?

Tags: harry-potter

In *The Chamber of Secrets*, a dueling club is formed. But we don't really know if there is precise rules on it, except from initial salutation.

Does a precise rules list exist?

[image]

Comment: I highly doubt it, even in-universe. A duel is just a fight given a fancy name; there might be some kind of formality about when and where it takes place (though even that's not a requirement), but anything that's "expected" (such as bowing at the start) is essentially going to be tradition.